# Html dash table

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, html-table, plotly-dash

I am trying to use dash to create a html table

My dataframe looks like this :

```
   Cap non-cap
0   A   a
1   B   b
2   C   c
3   D   d
4   E   e
..
26  Z   z
```

I want to display an html table just like the dataframe, but without the 0 - 26 index. 
The structure is

```
{'Cap' : ['A', 'B', 'C',....], 'non-Cap' : ['a','b','c',...]}
```

I tried :

```
return html.Table(
  [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +
  [html.Tr([
    html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
  ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]  
)
```

Answer (score 12):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

data = {'Cap' : ['A', 'B', 'C', ], 'non-Cap' : ['a','b','c', ]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def generate_table(dataframe, max_rows=26):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns]) ] +
        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )

app = dash.Dash(__name__, )

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H4(children='StackOverflow - Html dash table'),
    generate_table(df)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I would like to add more space between the columns names in the header. How Can I do it? I have tried [html.Th(col+ '    ') for col in dataframe.columns] but it doest work

Comment: Changes like that can be easily done with css, e.g.: `th {margin: 10px}`