# How do I return a dataframe from an app.callback with my as output as dbc.Table.from_dataframe

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, plotly-dash

I am trying to have a table load upon clicking a search button, and provide ID/password. My output is a dbc.Table.from_dataframe which allows an df argument; however when I use this as my output property, I am getting an error.

Here are the available properties in "my_table":
['children', 'id', 'style', 'className', 'key', 'tag', 'size', 'bordered', 'borderless', 'striped', 'dark', 'hover', 'responsive', 'loading_state']

I read the docs here
https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/table

I tried such using 'children' and that didn't work either.  I know with dcc table I need to return a dictionary, however I thought with dbc.Table.from_dataframe I can return a dataframe.

```
@app.callback(Output('my_table', 'df' ),
               [Input('search-button','n_clicks')],
               [State('input-id', 'value'),
               State('input-password', 'value')]
           )
def search_fi(n_clicks, iuser, ipasw):
    if n_clicks > 0:

        df = pd.DataFrame(
         {
             "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
             "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
         }
        return df
```

Comment: I haven't tried using the `dbc` components before, but you can see from the available properties that `df` is not allowed. What went wrong when you output to `children`? As an alternative, you could output to the `children` of a `div` and your function could `return dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df)`

Answer (score 5):

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Table', id='table-but', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('table-but', 'n_clicks')])

def search_fi(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
         {
             "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
             "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"]
         })
        print(df)
        return dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

or

- https://plotly.com/python/table/ figure
- [Html dash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52213738/html-dash-table)   html-table

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypY8C.png)